# Console.log shows my element as an array instead of an element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I'm doing a view where the customer is able to edit items, it comes with a filter so he/she can select between the options given. Everytime I edit it and save it works, however, if I return to the edit section the text box is empty and even though it was saved. If i use the inspect tool, the Console shows this:

```
impuestos_compra: Array [ {…} ]
```

If I open it, this is the information displayed:

```
impuestos_compra: (1) […]

"$$hashKey": "object:87"

0: Object { id: 2, empresa_id: 6, nombre: "IVA", … }
​​
length: 1
​​
<prototype>: Array []
```

This is the `<DIV>` label where I display this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
       <label>
           Impuestos de Mario
       </label>
       <select ng-model="articulo.impuestos_compra" name="impuestos_compra" class="form-control input-lg" required>
           <option value="">Seleccione impuesto de compra</option>
           <option ng-repeat="item in impuestos_compra" value="@{{ item.abreviacion }}">@{{ item.abreviacion }}</option>
       </select>
   </div>
```

In my try to iterate it, I did this code:

```
impuestos_compra = ['IVA' , 'IVAT0' ];
        impuestos_compra.forEach(function(impuestos_compra) {
            console.log(impuestos_compra);
        });
```

And, finally, the controller from Laravel with the edit function looks like this:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $articulo = Articulo::with('sat_producto:clave,descripcion', 'sat_unidad:clave,descripcion')->findOrFail($id);
    return view('panel.configuracion.articulo', [
        'id' => $id,     
        'presentaciones' => Presentacion::select('nombre')->get()->toArray(),
        'impuestos_compra' => Impuesto::select('abreviacion')->where('tipo' , 'compra')->get(),
    ]);
```

What am'I doing wrong? I tried `->get()->toArray()` and it works neither.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to change the variable name inside your `forEach` function, the array outside and the value inside both has same name.

Comment: Hi. I just did it and nothing changes for good :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `impuestos_compra` initialization. You can try pluck instead of select. Pluck returns the value of the column as a collection. Try the following code.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $articulo = Articulo::with('sat_producto:clave,descripcion', 'sat_unidad:clave,descripcion')->findOrFail($id);
    return view('panel.configuracion.articulo', [
        'id' => $id,     
        'presentaciones' => Presentacion::select('nombre')->get()->toArray(),
        'impuestos_compra' => Impuesto::where('tipo' , 'compra')->pluck('abreviacion')->toArray(),
    ]);
}
```